# SvelteKit-Firebase auth with firebase google auth code not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, sveltekit

```js
import { firebase, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx"
  };


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

**The code I have written is to implement google authentication in my web app. But it isn't working. It is throwing the error:**

```
The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/firebase_app.js?v=e56c4a7d' does not provide an export named 'firebase'
SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/firebase_app.js?v=e56c4a7d' does not provide an export named 'firebase'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Firebase Modular SDK but also using the name-spaced syntax. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import { firebase, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) has examples with both the syntaxes.

Comment: Can you please tell me the commands i need to run on my command prompt, to install firebase?

Comment: @34_ShravanNaik you seem to have installed it already.... `npm install firebase`